# How to use libgit2sharp with ssh-transport-protocol?

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

When I use libgit2sharp in project to clone repository with ssh-transport protocol, like

```
git@github.com:libgit2/libgit2sharp.git
```

It throw an exception, says "This transport isn't implemented. Sorry"

How can I clone repository with ssh-transport-protocol by using libgit2sharp ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, Ssh protocol is not supported yet. At this time only `git://` (read-only) and `http[s]://` protocols are.

However, it will eventually be, by leveraging the libssh2 library.

Subscribing to **[issue #255](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/255)** notifications will keep you updated about the progress made regarding this feature.

### Update:

There's a work in progress in libgit2 (see **[PR #2428](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/2428)**) that should help us make LibGit2Sharp able to cope with the ssh protocol sooner rather than later.

### Update 2:

**[PR #852](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/852)** is working on making ssh available to LibGit2Sharp

Comment: Thanks for this answer! So now there is no way to clone/push a git repository with ssh keys using LibGit2Sharp in a C# appliation?

Comment: Not yet. But LibGit2Sharp will eventually allow this feature.

Comment: Looks like there is some progress on libgit2 on this https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/2600

Comment: @RichardMitchell Subscribing to https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/852 would also be a good idea ;-)

Comment: Out of general interest, when this comes in, will Visual Studio automatically get this support? Is the (awesome) Git support in VS connected to this or another dependency?

Comment: If / when this lands in LibGit2Sharp it will *not* automatically get included in Visual Studio.  Sorry.  We have a policy to not ship cryptosystems or software that implements them (like libssh2) without review.

Comment: Can we get an Update 3?  Tried following the trail but after 10 minutes still haven't found current status

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, LibGit2Sharp does not include necessary crypto libraries out of box (https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/255#issuecomment-212580185).

Use [LibGit2Sharp-SSH](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LibGit2Sharp-SSH/) NuGet package (fork).

```
private void Run()
{
    var url = "ssh://username@gitblit.example.com/some/repository.git";
    var path = @"C:\Temp\some-repository";

    LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(url, path, new LibGit2Sharp.CloneOptions { CredentialsProvider = MyCredentialsProvider });
}

private Credentials MyCredentialsProvider(string url, string usernameFromUrl, SupportedCredentialTypes types)
{
    var sshDir = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), ".ssh");

    return new LibGit2Sharp.SshUserKeyCredentials()
    {
        Username = usernameFromUrl,
        Passphrase = string.Empty,
        PublicKey = Path.Combine(sshDir, "id_rsa.pub"),
        PrivateKey = Path.Combine(sshDir, "id_rsa"),
    };
}
```

Comment: From this sample it looks like you can't make its SSH implementation look up the user keys automatically, and have to guess whatever paths they might be at — manually in your code. Which is non-trivial.
Is the piece for keys selection from `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` totally missing from libssh2? Or is it possible to turn it on?

Comment: I don't know about LibGit2Sharp internals, but you may try to manually parse .ssh\config file. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/

Comment: My code throws a protcol error before it ever even reaches the credentials provider, so it can't be a key issue.  Apparently, libssh2 had a flaw and now this library cannot connect to any patched servers???

Comment: btw, this is a non-working code example, making use of variables that are not defined anywhere in your code sample.

Comment: Which variables are not defined?